# How do i check if a Queue<T> is full based on a specified number?

Tags: c#

check if queue has reached its limit which is 10.

Main program code:

```
//here im calling my class Queue
Queue queue = new Queue();
do
{
  string i  = Console.ReadLine();

  //first i check if the queue is full using my queue full function
  if(queue.queueFull() == true)
  {
    //if it is call this function
     queue.errorHandler();
  {
  else
  {
    if(i == "add")
      {
         queue.addItem();
         queue.displayQueue();
      }
  }
  // while loop will keep looping until it contains 10 elements if it does quueuefull() is 
  // supposed to be true and display error message.
}while(queue.queue.Contains(10))
```

Queue Class code:

```
public int orderNum {get; set;}
public Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();

public void addItem()
{
  Random rnd = new Random();
  int queueID = rnd.Next(1000,9999);
  orderNum = queueID;
  
  queue.Enqueue(orderNum);
}

public void queueFull()
{
  // quueueFull is supposed to return true if it has 10 elemnst inside
  if(queue.Count ==10)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

public void errorHandler()
{
   // this function will check if queueFull is returning true
   if(queueFull() == true)
    {
       Console.WritLine("full");
    } 
}
```

however this does not work and only lets me add one element and then breaks am i using Queue methods correctly and am i checking if its full correctly.

Comment: The `Queue` dynamically expands when new elements are enqueued, so there's no real notion of a "full" queue, at least with the class you're using.  You can, however, use the `Count` property to get the number of elements in the queue, if that solves your use-case.

Comment: [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.contains) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: i don't understand what the point of your question is, since you provided the _answer_ in the _code_ you've written for `queueFull()`.

Comment: Among other things, that is not the proper use of `Random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue.Contains()` is used to find if an element is in it, not to check for size.
Instead, you should use `queue.Count < 10`  in your `While` loop, or more if you want it to error.

Comment: He has already a method for this queueFull. He should just fix the compiler error and use that method.

Comment: `public void queueFull()` needs to have a return type of `bool` not `void`, `Console.WritLine` is misspelt, the bracket on top of `else` is the wrong way round...What IDE are you using? Notepad?

Comment: @Baron visual studio

Comment: @Baron ye sorry for the spelling errors i was typing the question on a different machine i coudlnt copy and past it.